# Sequelize ORM - How to make a model to have a array of objects, that are always in a specific persistent order

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to make a sequelize model that have an array of items(as below):

```
{
  id:1,
  name: Name,
  hobbies: [
      'hobby one',
      'hobby two',
      'hobby three',
      'hobby four',
  ]
}
```

Also i need to make sure the items in the array are in a specific order

Comment: Please refer the following blog https://medium.com/@eth3rnit3/sequelize-relationships-ultimate-guide-f26801a75554, I hope it will give you some direction

Comment: Mmm you need to be more precise with your question, depends of what do you need, in the most cases, you must to use relations like Users -> Hobbies, and use associations, scopes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example with relations

```
// Define Users
const Users = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.BIGINT, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true},
    name: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
});

// Define Hobbies
const UserHobbies = sequelize.define('UserHobbie', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.BIGINT, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true},
    name: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
}, {timestamps: true});

// Add Asocciation
Users.hasMany(UserHobbies, {
    as: 'hobbies',
    onDelete: 'cascade',
});

// Create scope 'withhobbies'
Users.addScope('withhobbies', {
    include: [{ // Add join to hobbies
        model: UserHobbies,
        as: 'hobbies',
        attributes: ['name'],
        orderBy: [ // Order by hobbie creation time (autogenerate by option timestamps: true)
           ['createdAt', 'ASC'],
        ],
    }],
});

// Use method to make final object
async function getUsersAndHobbies() {
    const users = await Users.scope('withhobbies').findAll(); // Use scope to include hobbies
    return users.map((u) => {
        const plain = u.get({plain: true}); // Get plain object
        return {
            ...plain,
            hobbies: plain.hobbies.map((h) => h.name), // override hobbies with only the names
        });
};
```

Example with setters and Getters:

```
// Define Users
const Users = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.BIGINT, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true},
    name: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    defaultValue: '[]',
    hobbies: {
       type: DataTypes.TEXT,
       get() {
           return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('hobbies'));
       },
       set(val) {
           if (!Array.isArray(val)) {
               throw new Error('hobbies must to be an array');
           }
           this.setDataValue('hobbies', JSON.stringify(val));
       },
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Exos, yeah i think this can work, what i was trying to do was to save an object to the db,

`{
    user: {
        name: 'someone',
        hobbies: [
           {name: 'hobby one', index: 0},
           {name: 'hobby two', index: 1}
        ]
    }
}`

i want the hobbies to be always in the order of index, and each user can have any number of hobbies, however i don't want index to be returned when queried